# Definition of a length metric.

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space. Define the *induced intrinsic metric* $\widehat{d}$ as follows
\begin{equation}
\widehat{d}(x,y) = \inf_{\gamma} \sup_{t_0, \ldots, t_N} \sum_{i=1}^{N}d(\gamma(t_{i-1}, \gamma(t_i)),
\end{equation}

where the infimum is taken over all smooth paths $\gamma$ connecting $x$ to $y$ and the supremum is taking over all subdivisions $(t_0, \ldots, t_N)$ of $\gamma$.

The metric space formed by $(X, \widehat{d})$ is called a length space. However a problem I'm looking at refers to a length metric. My question is what is a length metric? Is it just a metric $d$ that is defined as above?

Comment: A "length metric" would indeed simply be an induced metric $\hat d$ from a metric $d$ on a space $X$. If the problem simply refers to a "length metric," then either the underlying space is assumed, or is immaterial to what is being asked.

Comment: I think you mean _continuous paths_, not smooth ones. Smoothness doesn't have any meaning in a general metric space.